# Using JQuery How to Perform multiple Operation on a single Button

Tags: jquery

I have one button. When i click on this button, it will show one pop up model For confirmation. When i click on OK button, i want to perform two operation. First Operation is: It will remove one selected item form the dropdownlist and also insert the data in the table. So here First operation is Performing means it will remove the dropdownlist selected item, But data will not inserted in the table. So how can i perform two operation on a single Click button. Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show_confirm() {
    var r = confirm("Press a button");
    if (r==true) {
      alert("You pressed OK!");
// any number of actions that are to be performed when Ok is clicked can be done here.
      }
    else {
      alert("You pressed Cancel!");
      }
    }
    </script>

<input type="button" onclick="show_confirm()" value="Show confirm box" />
```

Do let me know if you need further help though.

Comment: Just i am sending my code to u. Please see it.  var value = $('[id$=DropDownList2] option:selected').text();

$('[id$=btn_SwitchOver]').click(function(event) {
 var message = "Do you want to Perform Switch Over Operation";
openConfirmationModal(message);
event.preventDefault();
 });

Comment: So here openConfirmationModel() function is there.

Comment: function removeValue(win)
  {         
       insertOperationType(groupid,type);
        UpdateOperationType( $('[id$=DropDownList2] option:selected').val());         
        win.closeModal();         
  }

Comment: and also function insertOperationType(groupid,type) is there.

Comment: Suppose In Your code: if i write one more function Show_Confirm2(), so how can i access the another function in OnClick event. Please ...

Comment: Why not write whatever code you wish to run as functions and call them ?

Comment: Well, late but, change the code to associate an onclick in an unobtrusive way and do all the needs in the handler. Call many functions or write all the code there.